# VS development server serving WCF services as plain text

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Whenever I load a WCF in my browser to see if its working I get the .svc source in plain text, for example:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Service="serv.Stocks" %>
```

instead of the normal output. This does not happens however if I host it in IIS.

I tried succesfully to reproduce it creating a whole new solution with only a wcf service so I dont think is something else in the solution causing problems.

I'm using VS 2010 in windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you "loading it in your browser"?  If your url begins with `file:///`, then you are simply viewing the file directly.  It has to be hosted *somewhere*, either in IIS, or debugging/running from VS 2010 with Cassini.

Comment: As the title says I'm using the development server, so I'm loading it using http://localhost:devport/something.svc (or with right click->view in browser which is the same thing)

Comment: Are you certain that the project is compiling and building properly?  i.e., when you run in debug mode, does it load the debugging profile in VS?  Can you tell me what project type you are using and the steps to create your service, so I can try to replicate on my Windows 7 / VS 2010 install?  I guess you could also try repair install VS 2010 in case something has been corrupted in your environment, or try the same solution on another dev machine and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: I pretty much followed this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service using VS 2010
Also I tried in a XP box with VS 2010 and the same happened.

Comment: Sounds like the VS web project isn't configured correctly. You're seeing text for the SVC file because the development server isn't recognizing it as an "executable" file. Look in the Web tab of the project properties to see if a specific page has been set as start up action. If that doesn't work, try creating a brand new web project and run it. It should show the default web page for an empty web project. If not, then your VS install/config may be corrupted.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling every framework version I had installed and 'repairing' VS. That did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your metadata publishable?

By this I mean an endpoint like this:

```
<endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

And a behavior like this:

```
<services>
  <service
      name="Metadata.Example.SimpleService"
      behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
    ...
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Without much more to go from I dont know where else to suggest?

Comment: I do, both the services and the behavior (both vanilla) sections are present with all the information you included.